# How to write AND operation for leftJoin() in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

i have a query where I come across this

```
left join `product_term_batch` as `ptb` on `ptb`.`batch_id` = `o`.`batch_id` and `ptb`.`product_id` = `o`.`product_id`
```

Piece of code how to convert into Laravel LeftJoin() function

**Edit1**

I know to write this

```
->leftJoin('product_term_batch as `ptb`',' `ptb`.`batch_id`','=',' `o`.`order_id`')
```

But what about the and part ?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a closure function to the `leftJoin` method, and inside of it, chain your `->on()`

```
->leftJoin(function($join){
    $join->on('product_term_batch as ptb', 'ptb.batch_id', '=', 'o.order_id')
    ->on('ptb.product_id', '=', 'o.product_id`');
});
```

Furthermore, your `backticks` aren't necessary as you have no non-confirming characters in table or column names.